# How can I start the regression from a certain year in SAS

Tags: sas

I am running the following simple linear regression:

```
    proc reg data=Nationalnew;
    model PE_PCHNG = HWOL_CHANGE;
    run;
```

My dataset starts with may of 2005m5. I am wondering if there is anyway that instead of going to my dataset and deleting the observations I don't need, that I can start the regression with 2006m12?

Comment: Do you have a date variable or other indicator of year/month on your data?  What is the format of that variable(s)?

Comment: @Joe. Yes I do. data basically looks like the following:

                          Date               PE_PCHNG   HWOL_CHANGE
                          01May2005       2                           -39

Comment: If your date_var is a SAS date or datetime you can add a WHERE clause to filter the date.

Comment: @Reeza, Can you give me an example please?

Comment: add the line `Where date_var >= '01Dec2006'd;` The exact code depends on your format.

Answer (score 1):

PROC REG supports a WHERE statement (as nearly every PROC does).  In your case, assuming `date` is a true date, you could run:

```
proc reg data=Nationalnew;
    where date > '01DEC2006'd;
    model PE_PCHNG = HWOL_CHANGE;
    run;
```

If the variable is date format but character, you use `input` to convert to date.